# Quasar BEX doesn't catch bridge.on('event') inside background-hooks emitted from dom-hooks

Tags: quasar-framework

Following [official Quasar documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-browser-extensions/bex-communication) I emit my event in  **dom-hooks.js**:

```js
export default function attachDomHooks (bridge) {
  const clickHandler = (event) => {
    bridge.send('message.to.quasar', { target: event.target })
  }
  window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, true)
}
```

Then I failed to catch it in **background-hooks.js**:

```js
export default function attachBackgroundHooks (bridge) {
  bridge.on('message.to.quasar', event => {
    console.log('message.to.quasar', event.data)
    bridge.send(event.eventResponseKey)
  })
}
```

Basically, I need to put some data into `chrome.storage` which I have inside background-hooks, but trigger this action from dom-hooks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show all your code from dom-hooks and background-hooks

Comment: @webnoob yup, just updated the question

Comment: The same code in content-hooks.js works perfectly. Created an issue https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/8174

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the content-hooks.js file as a proxy to forward on the event to the background script. **The dom cannot access the background script - this is by design.**

So as an example (untested):

dom-hooks:

```js
export default function attachDomHooks (bridge) {
  bridge.send('message.to.quasar', { from: 'dom-hooks' })
}
```

content-hooks:

```js
export default function attachContentHooks (bridge) {
  bridge.on('message.to.quasar', event => {
    bridge.send('message.to.quasar.bg', event.data)
  })
}
```

background-hooks:

```js
export default function attachBackgroundHooks (bridge) {
  bridge.on('message.to.quasar.bg', event => {
    console.log(event)
  })
}
```